# Django - Stop Page from reloading after GET Request

Tags: javascript, html, django, get-request

I'd like to show all grades from one user on Button Click. Now I wanted to integrate an expandable Button from Bootstrap. The GET Request works perfectly, but the JavaScript for the expandable Button gets triggered on Button Click and then the Page gets reloaded. That means the Button now is back at the original state. Do you guys maybe have a way to fix that?

noten.html

```
{% if subject_list %}
    <form name="subject-list" method="GET">
        <ul>
            {% for subject in subject_list %}
                <p>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#{{ subject }}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" value="{{ subject }}" id="{{ subject }}" name="subject">
                        {{ subject }}
                    </button>
                </p>
                <div class="collapse" id="{{ subject }}">
                    <div class="card card-body">
                        {% if grades %}
                            {% for grade in grades %}
                                <li>{{ grade }}</li>
                            {% endfor %}
                            {% else %}
                                <p>Du hast keine Noten in diesem Fach!</p>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </form>
{% endif %}
```

views.py

```
def noten(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:  # if user is logged in
        object_list = Subject.objects.order_by('name')
        subject_list = []
        for subject in object_list:
            subject_list.append(subject.name)

        if request.method == 'GET':
            subject = request.GET.get('subject', '')
            if subject != '':
                print(f"GET {subject}")
                grades = Test.get_grades(student=request.user.id, subject=subject, self=Test)
                return render(request, 'noten.html', {'subject_list': subject_list, 'grades': grades})
            else:
                return render(request, 'noten.html', {'subject_list': subject_list})
        else:
            return render(request, 'noten.html', {'subject_list': subject_list})
    else:  # else redirect to login page
        return redirect('loginForm:login')
```

Comment: A button with `type="submit"` (or no type defined) will submit the form. Change buttons that should not submit to `type="button"`.

Comment: But if I change it to be `type="button"`, it doesn't make a GET request.

Comment: Unfortunately the submission of a form results in a "refresh". To get around that you could use `event.preventDefault()` but this would also negate the GET request, so you would have to manually create the request in javascript. I'm not sure I can help with that, since I don't know Django. Sorry.